# How to use usort inside a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, loops, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array

```
[
    "/api/dns" => [
        0 => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "uri" => "foo0"
        ],
        1 => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "uri" => "foo1"
        ],
        2 => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "uri" => "foo2"
        ]
    ],
    "/api/servers" => [
        0 => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "uri" => "foo0"
        ],
        1 => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "uri" => "foo1"
        ],
        2 => [
            "method" => "GET",
            "uri" => "foo2"
        ]
    ]
];
```

I'm trying to sort by `uri`.

I tried with `usort` like this:

```
usort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
   return $a['uri'] - $b['uri'];
});
```

But this is not working because the sort is not done on right array so I got the error:

> Undefined index: uri

I tried to add this function in a foreach without result. I don't know why this is not working because the sort is done on the right array.

```
foreach ($myArray as $key) {
    usort($key, function ($a, $b) {
        return $a['uri'] - $b['uri'];
    });
}
```

Is this possible with `usort`?

How can I sort by `uri` with my `usort` function?

Comment: Do you want to sort each subArray or sort the entire array and if needed move subArrays? (Just go through your subArray by referenc: `foreach ($myArray as $key)` -> `foreach ($myArray as &$key)`)

Comment: Also note that if your `uri` keys are alphanumeric, `$a['uri'] - $b['uri']` doesn't work. use [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) instead.

Comment: @ Rizier123 To use `usort` in a `foreach`, he will need to work with reference `foreach ($myArray as &$key)`. By default, `$key` is a copy. There's no point of sorting a copy as it will be destroyed after the `foreach`

Comment: Okay thanks guys, I try this ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you loop through your first level, modify the subarrays "by reference" with the `&` symbol.

Code:  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/n7o6h))

```
foreach ($myArray as &$subarray) {
    usort($subarray, fn($a, $b) => $a['uri'] <=> $b['uri']);
}
```

If you don't want to use `&`, then you can directly overwrite elements by key name in the original array as you iterate. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IYU5I))

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $subarray) {
    usort($myArray[$key], fn($a, $b) => $a['uri'] <=> $b['uri']);
}
```

Alternatively, you can combine `array_multisort()` with `array_column()`:

Code:  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sOEqZ))

```
foreach ($myArray as &$subarray) {
    array_multisort(array_column($subarray, 'uri'), $subarray);
}
```

And again, you can perform iterated overwrites with this as well.